# wrap a 32 bit Advantage Data Provider into a COM+

Tags: sybase, components, advantage-database-server

How do I expose the functionality found in Advantage.Data.Provider.dll thru a wrapper.

My goal is to install/deploy the COM+ into a 64 bit server. The Advantage.Data.Provider.dll is a 32 bit driver. Don't want to upgrade to Advantage Database Server 9 which does support 64 bit. I have created a serviced .NET Component in c#, no problem setting it up. What I don't know is what to put inside of it. How do I expose the functionality found in the dll to the client code? I will clarify if you ask me to. Thanks, Chesterton

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to call the Advantage.Data.Provider.dll from a COM+ object on a 64-bit server. The Advantage.Data.Provider.dll calls ads32.dll, which is a 32-bit dll (version 9.1 and earlier). The ace32.dll cannot be called from a 64-bit process. Only if your COM+ object is running in a 32-bit process can it call ace32.dll successfully.

A C# application that calls the Advantage.Data.Provider.dll (and therefore, ace32.dll) must be targeted for x86 (32-bits).